# Reverse lookup of inode/file from offset in raw device on linux and ext3/4?

Tags: linux, ext4, ext3, inode

In linux, given an offset into a raw disk device, is it possible to map back to an partition + inode?

For example, suppose I know that string "xyz" is contained at byte offset 1000000 on /dev/sda:
(e.g. xxd -l 100 -s 1000000 /dev/sda   shows a dump that begins with "xyz")

1) How do I figure out which partition (if any) offset 1000000 is located in?(I imagine this is easy, but am including it for completeness)

2) Assuming the offset is located in a partition, how do I go about finding which inode it belongs to (or determine that it is part of free space) ?  Presumably this is filesystem specific, in which case does any one know how to do this for ext4 and ext3?

Comment: It is definitely possible and a few years ago I saw the HOWTO somewhere in the internet. The trick involves some math on different parameters of the filesystem and partition table. Try to search for it. This could be useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37119/find-which-files-are-affected-by-bad-blocks-on-ext4-filesystem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just had to do a similar thing, so I thought I'd share my solution.

You can see which partition a drive byte offset belongs to by checking the 'offset' and 'size' elements of the udisks --show-info output; e.g.

```
user@host:~$ sudo udisks --show-info /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'offset'
    offset:                    1048576
    alignment offset:          0
```

Subtract this offset from the disk offset to get the byte offset into the partition. So  disk offset (10000000) in /dev/sda is partition offset (10000000 - 1048576) = 8951424 in /dev/sda1

You can find out how large blocks are in a partition using the following command:

```
user@host:~$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1  | grep -i 'block size'
Block size:               4096
```

Divide the partition byte offset by the block size to determine the block offset, in this case 8951424 / 4096 = 2185

Run the following command to find out what inode occupies that block:

```
user@host:~$ sudo debugfs -R "icheck 2185" /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
Block   Inode number
2185    123456
```

then the following command to find out what the filename is for that inode:

```
user@host:~$ sudo debugfs -R "ncheck 123456" /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
Inode   Pathname
123456  /tmp/some-filename.txt
```

There's a longer description of how this at http://www.randomnoun.com/wp/2013/09/12/determining-the-file-at-a-specific-vmdk-offset

Comment: In case of BTRFS you need to convert the offset inside a partition to a "logical address" *(a btrfs internal address space)* and then use `btrfs logical-resolve`. For example: `btrfs inspect-internal logical-resolve 378331914240 /`. Converting the physical address to logical might be tough, I was given [this script on IRC channel #btrfs](https://github.com/Hi-Angel/scripts/blob/master/btrfs-physical-to-logical-mapping.py)

Answer (score 4):

Greg Knox's answer is correct, but could be easier. I've written a shell script, [lba2file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hackerb9/lba2file/master/lba2file), which performs all the arithmetic for you, source code below.

*[Update: Script no longer depends on `udisks` binary].*

### Example usage of lba2file

Solving the problem posed in the question (with address specified in bytes):

```
kremvax$ sudo lba2file -b 1000000 /dev/sda
Disk Byte 1000000 is at filesystem block 124744 in /dev/sda1
Block is used by inode 21762939
Searching for filename(s)...
Inode           Pathname
21762939        /home/lilnjn/backups/adhumbla_pics_2.zip
```

### Example usage with S.M.A.R.T.

If your hard drive has a bad sector, you may want to find out what file is corrupted before you remap the sector by writing zeros to it. You can do so easily using `smartctl` and `lba2file`.

```
kremvax$ sudo smartctl -C -t short /dev/sdd    
kremvax$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd | grep '^# 1'
# 1  Short captive   Completed: read failure   90%   20444   1218783739
```

The final number `1218783739` is the disk address in sectors, not bytes:

```
kremvax$ sudo lba2file 1218783739 /dev/sdd
Disk Sector 1218783739 is at filesystem block 152347711 in /dev/sdd1
Block is used by inode 31219834
Searching for filename(s)...
Inode           Pathname
31219834        /home/mryuk/2020-11-03-3045-us-la-msy.jpg
31219834        /home/mryuk/web/2020-11-03-3045-us-la-msy.jpg
```

### Discussion

My script defaults to a sector address (often called "LBA") rather than bytes. This is because LBA is what tools like `smartctl` will report when there is a bad block on the drive. However, if you want to specify bytes instead of sectors, just give the `-b` flag.

### Source Code

Cut and paste into a file or click [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hackerb9/lba2file/master/lba2file) to download from https://github.com/hackerb9/lba2file/

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# lba2file: Given an LBA number and a drive in /dev/, print which
# filename(s), if any, use that sector.

# This is the opposite of `hdparm --fibmap /foo/bar`

# B9 May 2020

if [[ "$1" == "-b" ]]; then
    BYTESFLAG=Byte
    shift
fi

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: lba2file  [-b]  <sector number>  /dev/sdX"
    echo "  -b: Use byte address instead of sector"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Please run as root using 'sudo $@'" >&2
    exit 1
fi

lba=$1
drive=$2
drive=${drive#/dev/}        # Remove /dev/ prefix, if any.

if [[ "$drive" =~ ^(.*)[0-9]$ ]]; then    # Either user specified a partition.
    searchparts="/sys/class/block/$drive"
    drive=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else                     # Or user specified a drive.
    shopt -s nullglob            # Don't use '?' literally.
    searchparts=$(eval echo /sys/class/block/${drive}?)
fi

for partition in $searchparts; do
    device=/dev/${partition#/sys/class/block/}
    cd "$partition" || continue
    start=$(cat "$partition/start")
    partitionsize=$(cat "$partition/size")
    hwsectorsize=$(cat "/sys/class/block/$drive/queue/hw_sector_size")

    # Typically: e2blocksize==4096, hwsectorsize==512
    # Example: start=1048576, partitionsize=640133980160
    # Do a sanity check.
    if [[ -z "$start" || -z "$partitionsize" || -z "$hwsectorsize" ]]; then
    echo "Error reading data for $device" >&2
    continue
    fi

    # Scale everything to bytes since we'll use that for debugfs.
    start=$((start * hwsectorsize))
    partitionsize=$((partitionsize * hwsectorsize))

    # If not using byte flag, scale the address, too.
    if [[ -z "$BYTESFLAG" ]]; then
    byteaddress=$((lba * hwsectorsize))
    else
    byteaddress=$lba
    fi
    if [[ $byteaddress -lt $start ||
      $byteaddress -ge $((start+partitionsize)) ]]; then
    #echo "Address $byteaddress is not within $partition"
    continue        # Not in this partition
    fi

    if ! e2blocksize=$(tune2fs -l $device 2>/dev/null |
               grep '^Block size' | egrep -o '[0-9]+'); then
    echo "Skipping $device, not an Ext2/3/4 partition" 
    continue
    fi

    # Scale address by filesystem blocksize to find filesystem block number
    e2blockaddress=$(( (byteaddress - start) / e2blocksize))

    Sector=${BYTESFLAG:-Sector}
    echo "Disk $Sector $lba is at filesystem block $e2blockaddress in $device"
    inode=$(debugfs -R "icheck $e2blockaddress" $device 2>/dev/null |
           tail -1 | cut -f2)
    if [[ "$inode" && "$inode" != "<block not found>" ]]; then
    echo "$Sector is used by inode $inode"
    echo "Searching for filename(s)..."
    debugfs -R "ncheck $inode" $device 2>/dev/null
    else
    echo "$Sector is not in use."
    fi
done
```

Comment: Awesome script. Used it to analyse output from blktrace. Helped me track which files are constantly being written to (in an embedded system)!

Answer (score 0):

The script can be further polished into some one-liner:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/<disk>                                        \
| grep '^Block size:'                                              \
| sed 's/.* //'                                                    \
| xargs expr '(' <LBA> '*' 512 - <partition offset in bytes> ')' / \
| sudo xargs -I{} debugfs -R 'icheck {}' /dev/<partition>
sudo debugfs -R 'ncheck <inode from prev commend>' /dev/<partition>
```

But you may also need to do some extra mapping if using LVM.